# Safely store code snippets in JavaScript and MySQL

Tags: code-snippets

I'm working on an online python learning project which shows an online compiler inside an iframe to make user able to run and test codes simultaneously with courses . I have an idea of saving users code input into a database so the next time that they load the compiler , be able to have their last inputed code . While the user's input can be retrieved with js , how can I safely store it in my database ? Note that the code snippet will be send to a PHP API and from that will be saved into the database . What i want to ensure is the security of either sending or receiving code snippet through this route ( JavaScript , PHP , MySQL )